# Create Virtual Machine of partitioned IDE HDD connected via USB/IDE adaptor

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an IDE HDD with its disk partitioned as *part1* and *part2* (and the Windows7-created "*System Reserved*" partition).

> I don't have the/a computer to boot it on.

It contains **C:** (*part1*) and **D:** (*part2*) drives, and **C:** is a working installation of Windows 7.

I can access the HDD on a laptop via USB to IDE adapter. It converts the HDD initial **C:** & **D:** to **E:** & **F:** drives on my laptop.

**How to create a *Windows 7* VM of the *C:* drive?** (that i access on my laptop as **E:** using the *USB to IDE* adapter)

Comment: I am fairly sure you need everything on one partition for P2V to work properly.

Comment: @John all i need is the Windows to boot. The D: drive contains only files unrelated to the Windows installation and i can copy them directly.

Comment: If everything but data is on one partition then VMware P2V or Virtual Box P2V should work.

Comment: None work, the drive does not have an IP address as requested by the app.

Comment: I am not sure what you can do. I do not think you can build a Windows 7 VM because I don't think Windows 7 patches run anymore. I am not certain but I do not think so.